# Excel Formula for Alternative True or False in a column

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am trying to write a formula to check if a column has alternative Correct or incorrect entries. So in Column F I have entries like:

```
F2=True
F3=True
F4=NA
F5=True
F6=False
F7=False
F8=True
and so on
```

So I am stuck at how to make True or False return only 1st occurrence alternatively. So the end result should be

```
F2=True
F3=NA
F4=NA
F5=NA
F6=False
F7=NA
F8=True
and so on
```

Thanks,
R

Comment: An if() statement comparing the value against the previous? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tricky because of working with NA but was able to get it with the ISNA formula.

1. First put `=E2` into cell F2 (assuming your data starts in E2)
2. Then put `=IF(E3=INDIRECT("F"&MAX(IF(NOT(ISNA(F$1:F2)),ROW(F$1:F2),0))),NA(),E3)` into F3. This formula looks to see what is above and compares it to the current row in column E
3. Finally, drag that formula down as far as you need